# query is responsing for some but not for some

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which is used for retrieving images from propertyimages table also i have
combined other tables to built my query.

What is my problem ? my problem is whenever i m searching for a value which is not exist and selecting a value from drop-down so its giving correct answer means empty.

but whenever i m selecting another value from drop down which is not exist but here its providing me a value which is not belonging to my search.

Below is my query

```
SELECT     
    properties.PropertyID,
    properties.PropertyDealType,

    provinces.ProvinceName,
    districts.DistrictName,

    propertyimages.ImageID,
    propertyimages.ImagePath,
    propertyimages.ImageName

 FROM properties, propertyimages, provinces, districts 

    WHERE provinces.ProvinceName='".$province."'
    AND   districts.DistrictName='".$district."'
    AND   properties.PropertyDealType='".$propertystatus."'
    AND   properties.ImageID=propertyimages.ImageID
    GROUP BY properties.ImageID
```

Comment: You are misusing Mysql's GROUP BY extension you will get indeterminate values for all fields except `properties.ImageID`

Comment: You have no join conditions relating the `provinces` and `districts` tables to `properties`. So it's returning a full cartesian product of all the matching rows in each table.

Comment: The problem would be obvious if you used ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of implicit joins, since you would notice the missing `ON` clauses when joining those tables.

Comment: In order to write a proper answer, you need to post the schema of the tables. We need to know what columns relate `properties` with `provinces` and `districts`.

Comment: I have not used join conditions in my other queries so they going well except this one